# PHP make array start from key / position

Tags: php, arrays

I want to tell my array to start from key position 2 and then loop through the entire array, including the values before key position 2. I just want to use one array and specify the key position I start looping from. For example, here I am using array_splice, but it does not do what I want it to, could you help me please?

```
$names = array('Bill', 'Ben', 'Bert', 'Ernie');
foreach(array_slice($names, 2) as $name){
   echo $name;
}

foreach(array_slice($names, 3) as $name){
   echo $name;
}
```

Comment: So you don't want to use `foreach` but `for`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the keys are irrelevant, you can splice the array twice, and merge the resulting arrays, like this:

```
$names = array('Bill', 'Ben', 'Bert', 'Ernie');
$start = 2;

foreach( array_merge( array_slice($names, $start), array_slice( $names, 0, $start)) as $name){
   echo $name;
}
```

You can see from [the demo](http://3v4l.org/rQSe7#v430) that this prints:

```
BertErnieBillBen
```

Alternatively, for efficiency, you can use two loops that are aware of wrapping around to the beginning, which will be more efficient since you are operating on the original array and not creating copies of it.

```
$start = 2;
for( $i = $start, $count = count( $names); $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $names[$i];
}
$i = 0;
while( $i < $start) { 
    echo $names[$i++];
}
```

You could also turn this into one single loop, and just encapsulate the logic for wrapping around inside the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$limit = 2; //so you can set your start index to an arbitrary number
$fn= function($a,$b) use ($limit){
  if(($a < $limit && $b < $limit) 
      || ($a >= $limit && $b >=$limit)) //$a and $b on the same side of $limit
        return $a < $b ? -1 : ($a==$b ? 0 : 1);
  if($a < $limit && $b > $limit) return 1; //because $a will always be considered greater
  if($a >= $limit && $b < $limit) return -1; //because $b will always be considered greater

};
uksort($arr, $fn);
foreach($arr as $v) echo $v;
```