# Start looping through a continuous array at a particular string in the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I need to continuously loop through until I get my outcome and then I will break the loop. I need to be able to start at a certain point of the array based on value of the string in the array.

Lets say I want to start on friday, then the continuous loop would start on friday and go from there before it stars over.

```
friday  //start here
saturday
sunday
monday
tuesday
wednesday
thursday
friday
...and so on
```

**My Code**

```
$array = array('monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday');

$infinate = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
foreach ($infinate as $key => $value) {
    //check stuff until I break the loop
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what value are you looking for in the array?

Comment: What is the backstory? What are you trying to accomplish/solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start = 4;
    foreach (array_merge(array_slice($array, $start), array_slice($array, 0, 7)) as $key => $value){
       echo $value.'<br>';
    }
```

found something very similar to your problem
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803929/php-make-array-start-from-key-position)